# Implementing an event listener

Tags: java, swing, methods, jcombobox, itemlistener

Question:

"Create  the beverageJComboBoxItemStateChanged method (which immediately follows loadCategory) and insert code that adds the String representation of the selected item to the ArrayList billItems. [Hint: Use the ItemEvent.SELECTED constant to determine whether an item is selected.]"

Now the method is: `private void beverageJComboBoxItemStateChanged( ItemEvent event ) {}`

The Instance variable ArrayList is: `private void beverageJComboBoxItemStateChanged( ItemEvent event )`

How do I create the `ItemEvent.SELECTED` inside the method I mentioned above?

Comment: WHY ARE YOU YELLING? Recommended reading: [Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: YOU COPY-PASTED THE SAME SNIPPET TWICE. Also, I removed your yelling.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

> "Hint:Use the ItemEvent.SELECTED constant to determine whether an item is selected"

```
if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
    // do something
}
```

Please take some time to go over the tutorial, [How to Write Item Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html). Better explanations and examples.

> "How do I create the ItemEvent.SELECTED inside the method I mentioned above"

You don't *create* it. You check against it, like the "hint" tell you do to.

Also see [How to use ComboBoxes: Handling Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners). There's a good section on why you should check the state change

Also make sure you call your methods from an *actual* `itemStateChanged` of an `ItemListener`